# add an expiration date to to a rails model saves nil instead of date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to make my expiration date populate in a rails app:

I added my column like this:

```
class AddExpirationToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :expiration, :date
  end
end
```

In my model I added :

```
  after_create :set_expiration_date

def set_expiration_date
  self.expiration =  Date.today + 30.days
end
```

but when I create the post, it saves nil in expiration field instead of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `after_create` you're setting that value after it has been saved in the database. You can use `before_create` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular scenario, you should be using: `before_save set_expiration_date`, that or just called save again (that would be redundant tho):

```
def set_expiration_date
  self.expiration =  Date.today + 30.days
  save
end
```

The one you're currently using is called after Base.save on new objects that haven’t been saved yet (no record exists).

[after_create api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set the value before saving, or save the value after setting it. I'd recommend the former:

```
before_create :set_expiration_date 

def set_expiration_date
  self.expiration =  Date.today + 30.days
end
```

There are a lot of callbacks you can tie this method to, after_create happens after the row is saved to the database, so your line is ineffective.